# Does startNativeTracing only trace native function call?

Tags: android

I was wondering startNativeTracing function only traces information in native function calls.

If I do something like this

```
    Debug.startNativeTracing();

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++){
        a = i;
        b = i*i;
        c = a*b;
    }
    Debug.stopNativeTracing();
```

then am I not going to get any information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [*documentation*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#startNativeTracing%28%29) it only works on emulator.

Also are you running the emulator with:

```
emulator -trace foo
```

If you want to trace the code in real hardware, use `startMethodTracing` method(but remember that native code is not traced)

Comment: I am running this on emulator and I could see the six trace files. But I was wondering if this nativeStartTracing method only traces information in native codes